# DB2 9.7 and WebSphere App Server network deployment 7.0

Tags: db2, cloud, websphere, websphere-7

Need you help.I am doing Failover Management for DB2 9.7. The platform is Linux. I am using WebSphere App Server, IBM HTTP Server, DB2 9.7.I need to do workload management and failover management. I am not sure how to start on it.

Answer (score 2):

DB2 9.7 allows failover through [HADR](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/t0051382.html). When a failover event  occurs, the applications connected to the primary DB2 server will encounter a failure in their open transaction, and automatically reconnect to the standby DB2 server.

Here is a page describing DB2's built-in [workload management feature](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.wlm.doc/doc/c0052594.html)

Comment: hey thanks for replying. Firstly i am using Cloud Computing to do it, so is there any difference? secondly, what do u think about this website http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-highavailabilitycloud/index.html ?